# How to create a thread to run a schedule in the background using Python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I would like to use the `schedule` library in to order to run a filename.py every day at the same time (17:00). I would like to run this schedule in the background. The example given in the documentation with my own criteria is as follows:

```
import threading
import time
import schedule

def run_continuously(interval=1):
    """Continuously run, while executing pending jobs at each
    elapsed time interval.
    @return cease_continuous_run: threading. Event which can
    be set to cease continuous run. Please note that it is
    *intended behavior that run_continuously() does not run
    missed jobs*. For example, if you've registered a job that
    should run every minute and you set a continuous run
    interval of one hour then your job won't be run 60 times
    at each interval but only once.
    """
    cease_continuous_run = threading.Event()

    class ScheduleThread(threading.Thread):
        @classmethod
        def run(cls):
            while not cease_continuous_run.is_set():
                schedule.run_pending()
                time.sleep(interval)

    continuous_thread = ScheduleThread()
    continuous_thread.start()
    return cease_continuous_run

def background_job():
    exec(open('/Users/filename.py').read())

schedule.every().day.at("17:00").do(background_job)

# Start the background thread
stop_run_continuously = run_continuously()

# Do some other things...
time.sleep(10)

# Stop the background thread
stop_run_continuously.set()
```

However, when I run this code nothing seems to happen for me. I'm unsure what values to put in the interval= and time.sleep() to suit my need. I would be very grateful if someone could clarify this for me.

Comment: The last line stops the background thread which is responsible for running scheduled tasks. You don't want that. Of course the program then won't stop anymore because it has to run this background thread.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this...Thanks a lot @MichaelButscher! I don't think I even need the time.sleep() command as I'm only running the schedule once daily.